# My word comparison program ignores my print function

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a part of my program. Its job is to take a string and compare word-by-word with the alphabet, and if a letter is matched with one in the alphabet, it will print out that letter. However, the program seems to ignore my print command and proceeds to do something else, leaving the output to be empty.

```
x = "DEWIOCJWO"
alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
m = 0
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] == alphabet[m]:
        print(alphabet[m])
        m = 0
        break
    else:
        m = m + 1
        continue
```

Comment: Why do you expect `x[i]` to ever equal `alphabet[m]`?

Comment: You don't compare everything to everything.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Are you trying to print the letters in `x` which are in `alphabet`? I.e. only the letters?

Comment: Sorry for my poorly worded question since  i have only studied Python for two weeks. What I meant to make this part of my program do is: it takes the first letter of the x string and takes the first letter (A) of the alphabet, and compares them. If they are not equal, it takes the next letter of the alphabet (B), hence m = m + 1. Otherwise, it stops taking letter and just prints out the current letter that matches the one in the x string, then m is reset back to 0 for the next letter in x string. Again, sorry for the ambiguity of my question, hopes this can clarify.

Answer (score 0):

if x and alphabet have a different length you can use:

```
x = "DEWIOCJWO"

alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"


for i in range(min((len(x),len(alphabet))):

    if x[i] == alphabet[i]:

 print(x[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this  code:

```
x = "DEWIOCJWO"
alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] in alphabet:
        print(x[i] )
    else:
        continue
```

**You made mistake by comparing alphabet(m) because m is increasing in each time**

And because of that you didn't have any matches for printing

So use `in`  to findout string contains alphabet or not and `print(x[i])` For printing which character is matching alphabet

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain your current logic, you'll need a 2nd for loop to properly iterate through alphabet. e.g.

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    for m in range(len(alphabet)):
        if x[i] == alphabet[m]:
            print(alphabet[m])
            break
```

A cleaner way to do this though is to use regex.

```
import re
x = "DEWIOCJWO"
for letter in re.findall(r'[A-Z]', x):
    print(letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

you are checking only if the characters from x are equal with 'A'

you can use :

```
x = "DEWIOCJWO"
alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

print(*[c for c in x if c in alphabet])
```

output:

```
D E W I O C J W O
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for X in x:
    if X in alphabet: print(X)
```

or

```
print(*[X for X in x if X in alphabet])
```

or

```
print(' '.join([X for X in x if X in alphabet]))
```

all give you what you want (print letters in x that are in alphabet)

Answer (score 0):

If you just wish to print the uppercase alphabets in the input string, this expression might do so:

```
import re
print(re.findall('[A-Z]', "DEWIOCJWO"))
```

#### Output

```
['D', 'E', 'W', 'I', 'O', 'C', 'J', 'W', 'O']
```

and you can count it too:

```
import re

print(len(re.findall('[A-Z]', "DEWIOCJWO")))
```

which prints `9`.